# How does change the default width in vuestic inputs components

Tags: forms, select, input, sass, vuestic

In my form, I used Vuestic inputs components text boxes, select and text areas but there width can not customize according to the my utilization

I used their classes and changed the width, and there are no any props to change the width

Answer (score 1):

You can change `--va-form-element-default-width` css variable.

```css
    :root {
      --va-form-element-default-width: 500px;
    }
```